# How to correct conditional Poisson standard errors for over-dispersion

Tags: regression, python, statsmodels, overdispersion

I want to estimate a conditional negative binomial model, which an economist might call a negative binomial model with individual fixed effects.
I use Python and statsmodels, which has a conditional Poisson model but not a *conditional* negative binomial model, as far as I know.
I want to follow [Allison and Waterman](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/%7Eallison/FENB.pdf) to estimate a conditional Poisson model and correct standard errors for over-dispersion as follows:

> A relatively
> simple approach is to estimate the β coefficients under the fixed-effects Poisson model, but
> adjust the standard errors upward for overdispersion. A commonly-used adjustment is to
> multiply the standard errors by the square root of the ratio of the goodness-of-fit chi-square to the
> degrees of freedom. (Either Pearson’s chi-square or the deviance could be used. )

However, I can't find Pearson's $\chi^2$ in the output of statsmodels' `ConditionalPoisson` fit summary.
A comment on a [recent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/525494/1445) suggests that I should separately estimate $\chi^2$.
However, I don't see a fit method to estimate $\chi^2$, and the fit predict method (to manually calculate $\chi^2$) returns `NotImplementedError`.

How do I correct conditional Poisson standard errors in statsmodels for overdispersion?

Here's starter code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.discrete.conditional_models as cm

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'i': (np.arange(10000) // 200) + 1,
        't': (np.arange(10000) % 200) + 1
    }
)

np.random.seed(2001)
df['x'] = np.random.normal(loc=df['i'])
df['y'] = np.random.negative_binomial(np.exp((df['i'] + df['x'])/10), 0.1)

df1 = df.groupby('i').filter(lambda x: x['y'].var() > 0)

m1 = cm.ConditionalPoisson(
    endog=df1['y'],
    exog=df1['x'],
    groups=df1['i']
)

f1 = m1.fit(method='newton', cov_type='cluster')

print(f1.summary())


                 Conditional Logit Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                10000
Model:             ConditionalPoisson   No. groups:                         50
Log-Likelihood:           -1.1662e+09   Min group size:                    200
Method:                        newton   Max group size:                    200
Date:                Sat, 29 May 2021   Mean group size:                 200.0
Time:                        10:06:49                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x              0.1003   6.95e-05   1443.904      0.000       0.100       0.100
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Use quasilikelihood. R has a family function `quasipoisson` for that, Python maybe have something similar. Alternatively, use robust standard errors. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201903/how-to-deal-with-overdispersion-in-poisson-regression-quasi-likelihood-negativ

Comment: It looks like statsmodels does not allow overdispersion corrected or heteroscedasticity robust standard errors for conditional models for Logit and Poisson. Those are available for the "standard" models. GLM has both. Discrete models like Logit, Poisson. NegativeBinomial only have robust standard errors, HC, cluster, ..., but not simple overdispersion correction.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for the link! I hoped for a way to modify SEs in statsmodels. I use `feglm` and `feglm.nb` from the `alpaca` package for fixed-effect models in R, but I want to switch to Python completely.

Comment: @Josef, I'm OK without a canned solution. Is there a way to calculate $\chi^2$ for `ConditionalPoisson` results? If I can calculate $\chi^2$, I can adjust SEs following the Allison paper linked above. If you're the Josef P. from statsmodels, thanks for all the hard work! statsmodels gets me very close to a complete switch from R to Python!

Comment: I have not looked at the literature for this. I'm not sure how chi2 is defined for this. The conditional model removes the individual specific intercept and that will not be available for prediction. i.e. How are fittedvalues and Pearson residuals defined for conditional models? https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7469

Comment: AFAICS, `feglm.nb` just fits a standard fixed effects model and is not a conditional model that conditions out the individual heterogeneity. The only difference to standard GLM/NegativeBinomial seems to be computational in that it can handle more fixed effects.